# Linenumber of specific line in a file

Tags: bash

I'm fairly new to bash programming, and I am trying to figure out a way of "grepping" a line with a certain pattern from a rather long logfile and proceeding from the line I just got with `grep -w "pattern" filename`. I need to get to the line immediately preceding my grep-line.

I thought I could access it via linenumbers, but I only ever seem to find solutions that read a certain line via linenumber, if I already know, what that linenumber is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can tell `grep` to output additional lines of *context* around each matching line e.g.

```
grep -w "pattern" -A5 filename
```

for 5 lines of context after the match, or

```
grep -w "pattern" -B5 filename
```

for 5 lines of context before the match, or

```
grep -w "pattern" -C5 filename
```

for 5 lines each of before and after context. So in your case you could do

```
grep -w "pattern" -B1 filename | head -1
```

to find "pattern" and print a single preceding line of context, and then only print the context line using `head`. Other solutions using `awk` or `sed` instead of `grep` would be possible.